# Enterprise Architect API DiagramObject Update Fails

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am using the EA COM API via C# and trying to create the following hierarchy model:

```
Root (Package)
|
|--RootDiagram (Diagram:CompositeStructure)
|
|--TopPart (Element:Part, IsComposite=true)
    |
    |--TopPartDiagram (Diagram:CompositeStructure)
    |
    |--SubPart (Element:Part)
        |
        |-Port (Element:Port)
```

I use the Diagram.DiagramObjects.AddNew interface to add:

1. TopPart to the RootDiagram
2. SubPart to the TopPartDiagram
3. Port to the TopPartDiagram

Unfortunately the DiagramObject.Update succeeds only for 1 and 2. When I try to add the Port element, the process crashes with exception.

Via the GUI, I can add it by right clicking the SubPart and selecting Structural Elements. Why can't the automation API do the same thing?

**EDIT**
I elaborated the question with code snippet on Sparx forums. Please see: http://www.sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,40185.0.html

Comment: As I told you on Sparx' forum you're riding the wrong horse. You need to understand the basic API principles first.

Comment: It appears to be an EA bug.